# Why does sql concatenate number and string together when adding them

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

Can someone please explain to me why both of these evaluate to 246?

```
select 123 + '123'

select '123' + 123
```

Obviously the string in both cases is being converted to a number. But why?

This is Transact SQL

Comment: Please can you edit your question and tag the database you are using

Comment: For T-SQL (the dialect of SQL Server) the answer is simply: because that's how implicit conversions work. `INT` has a higher [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) than any string type. One can certainly question the sanity of this setup, but it's documented. (You can get slightly more sane behavior using `CONCAT`, which always converts to string first and converts `NULL` to the empty string: `CONCAT(123, '123')` and `CONCAT('123', 123)` both yield `123123`.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert if that was an answer rather than a comment I could mark it as the answer. It was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In Transact-SQL, when an operation is performed between a character string and a numeric value, the string is implicitly converted to a numeric type if possible [since INT has a higher precedence than the STRING type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

1. `select 123 + '123'`: In this case, the numeric value 123 is added to the character string '123'. Since the addition operator (+) is defined for numeric values, the string '123' is implicitly converted to a numeric type. Therefore, the string '123' is treated as a numeric value and added to 123, resulting in the value 246.
2. `select '123' + 123`: Here the string '123' is concatenated with the numeric value 123. The concatenation operator (+) is defined for string values, so the numeric value 123 is implicitly converted to a string type. The string '123' is then concatenated with the string representation of 123, resulting in the string '123123'.